# My application works on Android version from 4.* to 4.4.2 but not on 4.4.3

Tags: android, compatibility

It seems strange, but I have several users who don't experience any trouble, and two others who do.

I can't see any difference but one : the version. The two users with the "not working" app are using Android 4.4.3.
All the others are using older versions.

The problem *seems* to be with the function ".isChecked()" on a radioButton (in a radioGroup).
It keeps sending "false" even if it is true.

I am absolutely sure it is the same version (I sent my app by the same email to all the users).

I do not understand this problem, it seems strange in this way. The function "isChecked" exists since the first API ! (according to the official developer website)

If anyone has an idea...
Thanks !

Comment: Please show us your code. You're making too many assumptions about your code as it is. Try to assume that .isChecked() is working perfectly as intended even on Android 4.4.3 and that the fault doesn't lie there (despite the obvious connection you've made).

Comment: What are you getting in your LogCat when that Exception occurs?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using a `android:targetSdkVersion` that is below the two user where the app is not working .

try to change this code in you `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="minimun target android version "
        android:targetSdkVersion="it should be < = to your friend's android version " />`

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I changed targetSdkVersion to 20, but it didn't make any difference...

Comment: change `minSdkVersion` also ,set it equal to you friend's android version